# How to View YouTube API User Requests Limit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm developing a personal-use app that's using the YouTube Data API v3 for a number of operations, including creating live streams/broadcasts, creating playlists, etc. My app status is Testing with myself added as a test user. Until yesterday, I haven't had any issues with this.

Yesterday, when developing some new features and testing, I started hitting quota limits. Specifically, `Error 403: User requests exceed the rate limit, userRequestsExceedRateLimit`.

I can't figure out how to see the user requests quota that I'm exceeding. I went to manage the YouTube Data API v3 and clicked on the Quotas tab, and only see 3 quotas:

```
Queries per day - 60% usage (10k limit)
Queries per minute - 0% usage (1.8M limit)
Queries per minute per user - "Per-user quota usage is not displayed" (180k limit)
```

I don't see any per user quotas other than the per minute, and I'm certainly not doing anywhere near 180k queries per minute, else I'd have vastly exceeded the daily query limit, which I haven't.

I can't find anywhere else to see this user limit I'm hitting. This started last night, I left it alone and it's still happening today (today my queries per day usage is 0%). I'm assuming (hoping) as it hasn't been quite 24 hours yet that the quota will start freeing up once I hit that 24-hour mark, but I'd still like to know how to view this so I can keep an eye on it.

Interestingly, I used another Google account to generate new oauth id/secret pair and oauth'd into the same YouTube account and received the same error. So it seems as though the limit is based on the YouTube account authorizing the app, not on the oauth id/secret pair. But I still don't know where/how to view those limits.

Comment: Slow down your going to fast. project based quotas free up at midnight west cost USA time.  User based quotas normally free up after a couple of hours.    Creating a new client id and secrete in the same project is going to use the same quota.

Comment: The quota took 24 hours to free up. It did not allow me to make further API requests at midnight west coast time nor within a couple of hours. I also did not create new credentials in the same project, I used an entirely different account to create the new credentials. Also, I still would like to know where to view the user request quotas that I was exceeding.

Comment: Quota sometimes  take an hour to show updated data. Maybe you expect to see your usage in realtime?

Comment: Realtime or near realtime would be nice, but no, I checked over the course of several hours and the status didn't change. And since I generated a new client id and secret in a completely separate account that had no quota usage yet, but still received the same error when using the same YouTube account to authorize the app, it seems to be specific to the account authorizing, not the account generating the client id and secret. I just don't see anywhere on the youtube account (or the cid/csecret generating account) to view quotas imposed on the authorizing account.